# How to access cpanel hosted PHP file

Tags: php, cpanel, web-hosting

I have uploaded my .php files into cPanel. lets say my main domain is `abcde.com`. Then I created a subdomain called `gisWeb`.

Now in file manager under `/home/abcdec` I can see a directory called `gisWeb.abcde.com`. I uploaded an index.html file into this directory and tried to run it by browsing `http://gisWeb.abcde.com/index.html`but I'm getting site cant reach page. `

We can’t reach this page.
Try this
Make sure that you’ve got the right web address:`

How can I access my files.What should be the url?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: ask your host..

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be one of these. 
1. Sub-Domain you created may not have propagated.
2. You may need to put the files in public_html folder inside gisWeb.abcde.com